# Why does the ansible option "--private-key" works on one host but not on another?

Tags: ansible

I installed ansible 2.8.0 on VM-1 without modifying any other default configs in ansible.cfg except the **"host_key_checking = false"**.

Then I ran `ansible all -i "<IP of VM-3>," --private-key <key of VM-3> -u root -m ping` with OK on VM-3, but ran `ansible all -i "<IP of VM-2>," --private-key <key of VM-2> -u root -m ping` with ERROR on VM-2.

I generated a pair of ssh-key on VM-2 (user is root) and copy its private key (id_rsa) content to VM-1. I save it in a file named 'key', and set this file's mode to be '700'. Finally, I ran the command below:

```
ansible all -i "<ip of VM-2>," --private-key key -u root -m ping
```

It works wrong. The error info is:

```sh
/opt # ansible --version
ansible 2.8.0
  config file = /opt/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.6.8 (default, Apr  8 2019, 18:17:52) [GCC 8.3.0]
/opt # ls
ansible.cfg  key
/opt # ansible all -i "192.168.100.100," --private-key key -u root -m ping
192.168.100.100 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: root@192.168.100.100: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

Then I turned to use option "-k" instead, and it works.

```sh
/opt # ansible all -i "192.168.100.100," -k -u root -m ping
SSH password: 
192.168.100.100 | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
```

Then I tried again on VM-3 with the same steps of VM-2. The command using "--private-key" works. The environment of VM-2 and VM-3 are very similar.
I didn't find any difference between VM-2 and VM-3's sshd configure at all.

So I got very confused with these above.

In addition, the "--private-key" command will be OK after the "-k" command was run, because there is a ansible process living on the background, like this:

```sh
/opt # ansible all -i "192.168.100.100," -k -u root -m ping
SSH password: 
192.168.100.100 | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
/opt # ps -ef |grep ansible
  126 root      0:00 ssh: /root/.ansible/cp/e42d5dc861 [mux]
/opt # ansible all -i "192.168.100.100," --private-key key -u root -m ping
192.168.100.100 | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
```

I want to know how to use "--private-key" correctly in ansible command line.

Comment: It looks like you didn't add the needed public key to the user's `authorized_keys` on VM2.

Comment: Yeah, I misunderstood the working principle of ssh authentication. Whether to send a public key from A to B or hold a private key of B on A, the public key (which matched the private key used by A when connect to B) must be written into the "authorized_keys" file of B. Public key file (id_rsa.pub) on B is none sense in the authentication process.

Comment: @BCA - If you managed to solve the problem, you can post an answer yourself. It will help other people who stumble across the same issue in the future.